# Enable and Disable a service

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, error-log

my log service code:

```
public class LogService
{
    private static LogService _instance;
    public static LogService Instance
    {
        get
        {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new LogService();

                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ErrorLog(string log)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(log);
    }

    public void WarningLog(string log)
    {
        Trace.TraceWarning(log);
    }
}
```

I want  a **clean** way to enable and disable this service. 
for example:

```
if (some_variable == false) {
    // ignore all logService calls
}
```

what is the best way to do that?

Comment: I think the way you wrote is the correct one ( storing enabled/disabled flag )

Comment: Read an attribute from the `web.config` and if it does meet your specified criteria enable the service. If not, disable the service.

Comment: IMHO you should not. Instead you should control the listeners that are using the service to write the output somewhere. So just disable / remove any listeners. That's how many logging frameworks work.

Comment: Hi guys, i want to use a flag but in a clean way. i don't want to check that flag inside ErrorLog function (for example, i will have many more) and only if the value is T to call Trace.TraceError(log). i believe there is a nicer way, am i wrong?

Comment: in what context do you want to enable/disable? at application startup time or whilst its running?

Comment: @MikeD at application startup

Comment: might be over engineering, but I'd consider having a fake logging service that literally did nothing.  I'd inject that at application startup rather then the real useful one.  
this is to keep the use of the logging service, more pure.... rather than adding in extra code to handle this particular circumstance.

although, its just as quick to initialise your logging service with a parameter, which instructs it to 'drop' any log messages sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want a "cleaner" way than to place an `if (!IsLoggingEnabled()) return;` in every method, then you could look into Aspect Oriented Programming, where you simply place an attribute on the class or on relevant methods and the actual code will be emitted during or after compile-time.

But that might be overkill for replacing a few `if()` statements.